# Run a TimerTask or a Handler ALWAYS correctly

Tags: java, android, wakelock, android-wake-lock, standby

I have a problem (that's why I'm here :P):

I am running a TimerTask and/or a Handler. They should do something every second, no matter if the screen is on or not (standby). The problem is, after some time (2 to 10 hours) this process becomes weird timed. Sometimes it takes 10 seconds, sometimes 4 hours etc.

Now, I've read that you can use a Partial Wake Lock to solve this issue. Tried it, but it has not solved my issue (Maybe you should know that another library is also using a WakeLock which gets released after some time, but mine never gets released by me).

Maybe you should also know that the task/runnable runs on an asynctask (so on it's own thread). The wakelock is created from outside.

---

Edit:

Maybe it's good to know that it's a device owner app. Also, I know of the battery drain problem, but I still need it. The app really has to process this every second. I just need a solution for it, any, no matter which.

---

Edit 2:

Here's my current WakeLock code, which is started when my custom application reaches onCreate. As I said, it is never released.:

```
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"CustomWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: `Timer` are very expensive in terms of CPU. And why do you have to do task on each second even if device is on  standby. However i am quite confused here if you are talking about a background working(Service) or forground(Activity). Provide the full explanation of problem with code.

Comment: @ADM `Timer` is just a `Thread` that calls `wait()` in its main loop - so it is not that `"very expensive in terms of CPU"` - it does not [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)

Comment: Thx for clarification @pskink. What you think of above question?

Comment: well i think if the OP wants his device to be in standby mode all the time he will kill his batteries very soon ;-( but yes, i agree such background tasks shouldnt be done in foreground activities

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your help!. I know of the battery drain problem. But I still have to do it. Actually it's a Device Owner App and made for work. But I need a solution for it.

Comment: so use `WakeLock`, it will prevent your device from sleeping, whats your current code?

Comment: @pskink Added a second edit, you can check it out

Comment: @pskink If you say "prevent from sleeping": Does that mean it does not get locked by itself (the device) or the cpu runs its work in the standby mode on?

Comment: if you dont use any wake locks your device will sleep when you press the power button, to prevent it from sleeping the wake locks have to be acquired

Comment: ok do you have repeating `TimerTask`? or you call `schedule()` inside `TimerTask#run` method to kick yourself? did you try to use `HandlerThread` instead?

Comment: @pskink I'm calling schedule inside TimerTask.  I have not tried HandlerThread, what's the difference?

Comment: `HandlerThread` is more "android-ish" as it uses the `Looper` / `Handler` / `MessageQueue`